# How to make a checkbutton label selectable in gtk

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I'm creating some gui with pygtk and I want to make a `chekbutton label` selectable, is there a way to do it without subclassing?.

I was thinking to pack a checkbutton without label and a label in some container to do it, but I want to know if there is some method to access the checkbutton label and make it selectable.

I read the documentation but I was wondering if there is some missing method (sometimes that happen). Thanks.

Comment: You can get the GtkLabel that's on a GtkButton by default with the `get_child()` method (though IDK if you'll need to navigate the widget hierarchy a bit more or not). I don't know if making the label selectable will interfere with the checkbox's clicking behavior; you'll have to find out and report back :/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i try getting the label with get_child() and works, but can't make it selectable with set_selectable(True), I don't know why, but I think that maybe is beacuse i have various chekbuttons in a grid then the grid is packed in a scrolled window and this is packed in a box. Perhaps some methods doesn't work if the widget is packed in some specific container.

Comment: You should post a minimal example of the code that you attempted and doesn't work. If you do that more people (including myself) will be more willing to give it a shot.

Comment: By the way, clicking the label also activates the checkbutton, are you really really sure is a good idea to remove this behavior?

Comment: Thanks anyway, but i solve the problem using other method. (packing a checkbutton and a label).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkbutton.get_child().set_selectable(True)
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, but i've already try this and it doesn't work, maybe is because the checkbutton is in a scrolled window, perhaps some properties are setting to some values when the widget is packed in some specific container.